# What's the meaning of [Drupal 10.0.x will receive security coverage until December 2023.] in release note

Tags: security, upgrading

What's the meaning of [Drupal 10.0.x will receive security coverage until December 2023.] in release note. Can I continue to use Drupal 10.0.x after December 2023, is there any problem that I need to consider if I still use Drupal 10.0.x after December 2023.

Comment: What is the problem with updating to Drupal 10.1.x?

Comment: After December, 2023, Drupal 10.0.x will not get updates to fix security issues, which means security issues in Drupal 10.0.x can be used to exploit the site. I think that is a problem enough to update to Drupal 10.1.x, on sites that are publicly accessible.

Comment: For maintaining software security you have to look at the release cycle of the software product. For Drupal this is a 6 month cycle and the support is for two minor versions at the same time, so you can be max. 12 months behind.

Answer (score 1):

Security bugs in 10.0.x will no longer be fixed after that date. That version will be “end-of-life”.